# JavaFX Toggle visibility of self within controller

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a StackPane made up of BorderPanes that are included from elsewhere. All but the first pane are set to visible=false. Here's a generalised example of what I have:

Stacks.fxml

```
<StackPane fx:controller="StackController">
    <fx:include source="borderOne.fxml" />
    <Button fx:id="showBorderTwo" text="Show Border Two" />
    <fx:include fx:id="borderTwo" source="borderTwo.fxml" visible="false"/>
</StackPane>
```

StackController has:

```
public class StackController extends StackPane implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    Button showBorderTwo;
    @FXML
    BorderPane borderTwo;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        showBorderTwo.setOnAction((event) -> {
            borderTwo.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Now, that part works fine. However, BorderTwo has:

BorderTwo.fxml

```
<BorderPane fx:controller="BorderTwoController">
    <Button fx:id="close" text="Close" />
</BorderPane>
```

BorderTwoController

```
public class BorderTwoController extends BorderPane implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    Button close;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        close.setOnAction((event) -> {
            setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("visible: " + visibleProperty().toString());
        });
    }
}
```

The application starts without showing border two (correct).

The "show border two" button shows border two (correct).

The "close" button **does not hide the border two pane**.

Interestingly, **the print statement says that the visible property is now false** after setting it to false, despite the BorderPane remaining visible on the screen. What's going on here? I'm using JavaFX 8u60.

Comment: `BorderTwoController` does not become part of the scene graph; it's just a controller that happens to extend a `Node`. Modifying the properties of a node that is not part of a scene does not affect the rendered result at all. If you're loking for the [Custom Component approach](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components): That's implemented a bit differently and if you use that approach, you also need to change the way you use it in the other fxml.

Comment: @fabian I didn't want to use custom components in this situation, since BorderTwo will never be re-used elsewhere (I'm using custom components elsewhere in the application for things that will get re-used multiple times). Have you got a link that explains why BorderTwoController doesn't get included in the scene graph? I thought that's what fx:include did?

Comment: Ah, right I've just realised what I've done wrong and what you mean by that. I'll add my solution as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution thanks to a comment. I was confusing controllers and custom components. Solved it by changing:

BorderTwo.fxml

```
<BorderPane fx:id="menu" fx:controller="BorderTwoController">
    <Button fx:id="close" text="Close" />
</BorderPane>
```

BorderTwoController.java

```
public class BorderTwoController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    BorderPane menu;

    @FXML
    Button close;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        close.setOnAction((event) -> {
            menu.setVisible(false);
        });
    }
}
```

BorderTwoController, despite extending a BorderPane, was not actually a StackPane as it was just a controller for the BorderTwo.fxml. Adding an fx:id to the BorderTwo.fxml and then linking to this from the controller to toggle visibility worked just fine.